# React Native: I used CRNA, but navigation does not work

Tags: react-native, navigation

I tried React Native's CRNA as:

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
create-react-native-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```

However, navigation does not work (it should be very basic, am I right?).
I used the sample from the video "React Native Crash Course", the navigation exmple. However, I got the following errors:

> Navigator is deprecated and has been removed from the package........

I tried the following, but result the same.

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

Anyone know what I missed?

Comment: have you tried npm install react-native-navigation, and import from there?

Comment: No, the error remains the same. Where may I post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still want to use Navigator, then you can try to use [react-native-deprecated-custom-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-deprecated-custom-components).

Then you can import the package like this:

```
import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
```

And use like this (example):

```
<NavigationExperimental.Navigator
    // Default to movies route
    initialRoute={{ name: 'movies' }}
    // Use FloatFromBottom transition between screens
    configureScene={(route, routeStack) => NavigationExperimental.Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
    // Pass a route mapper functions
    renderScene={RouteMapper}
/>
```

Hope it can help you! :)